# Is it better to store data nested of flat in Elastic Search for analysis in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have decided to store some data in Elastic Search for the purpose of analysis in Kibana. We rely on dynamic mapping in Kibana for the time being.

Is it better to store data in this nested way:

```
project: {
  id: 1,
  path: [1],
  device: {
    id: 2,
    path: [1,2],
    accessory: {
      id: 3,
      path: [1,2,3]
    }
  }
}
```

or to send more normalized data like this:

```
project: {
  id: 1,
  path: [1]
}

device: {
  id: 2,
  path: [1,2]
}

accessory: {
  id: 3,
  path: [1,2,3]
}
```

Or is there a third much better way to store the data above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your example's structure, nesting should be more helpful.

Let's assume that your project has more than one device and each device has more than one accessory. Your structure could look like this:

```
{
    id: project1,
    ...,
    devices: [
      {
          id: dev1,
          name: device1,
          ...,
          accessories:[
              {
                  name: accessory1.1,
                  id: acc1.1,
                  ...
              },
              {
                  name: accessory1.2,
                  id: acc1.2,
                  ...
              }
          ]  
      },
      {
          id: dev2,
          name: device2,
          ...,
          accessories:[
              {
                  name: accessory2.1
                  id: acc2.1,
                  ...
              }
          ]  
      }
   ]
}
```

The advantages of using this kind of structure:

- Your mappings and settings will only be focused on your projects' structure instead of defining multiple settings and mappings for each: projects, devices, accessories.
- Additional, you will avoid "normalizing" your docs. Normalizing means that the projects, devices and accessories would have the same fields and expect the same type of values.
- You can add or remove devices or accessories from your projects if needed without affecting more than one document.
- You can create dashboards within Kibana to analyze your data based on certain fields. The dashboards accept aggregations and you can make the data refresh every 5 seconds.

Some disadvantages I can find:

- If you're new with ES, the queries might be a little confusing at the beginning.
- If you remove a project, the whole information, including devices and accessories will be removed as well. Be careful with it.
- Aggregations might affect a little to your performance. But this is more related to infrastructure (HW, cluster design, etc).

Finally, if you want to store individually the info for project, devices and accessories, you can use an index for each, but the relationships between them might not be that easy to keep and the queries will get very complex.

Hope this is helpful! :D